# cv2- display images in same window, one after the other

Tags: python, opencv

Iam trying to display images 1 after the other.

So I want to open image1.png, check it visually, then after clicking any button I want to open image2.png on the same window. Currently, cv2 is closing window of image1 then opening another window in different location in the screen which is confusing.

Any advise?

```
import cv2
imagespath=['image1.png','image2.png']
for a in imagespath:
    img=cv2.imread(a)
    imgx = cv2.resize(img, (1200, 800))
    x = 0
    while x==0:
        cv2.imshow(a, imgx)#image name same as filename
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the code you post will only open _one_ window, called `img`. that contradicts what you say.

Comment: yes, because i tried simplifying the original long code, not thinking it was the problem, anyway i will edit the question to reflect the correct condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make a named windows at the beginning, and then use it:

```
cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# [...]
cv2.imshow("img", imgx)
```

Edit: Christoph Rackwitz is right, no need to call cv2.namedWindow. It is sufficient to always use the same name of the window.

Comment: Thanks . Actually problem i was having is I was putting different name for each image based on the imagefilename, based on above i corrected that. thanks

Comment: you **do not need** to call `namedWindow`. a window of the required name is created automatically by the `imshow` call.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```py
cv2.imshow(a, imgx)#image name same as filename
```

to

```py
cv2.imshow('pic-display', imgx)
```

so that the new image gets displayed to the same window named 'pic-display'